# How do I uninstall Yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

How can I uninstall yarn? I've used it for a react-native project and now whenever I move the code out of `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js` it throws an error so I'd like to just use npm but whenever I initialize a react-native project it defaults to yarn. I tried `npm uninstall yarn` but that didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have it installed globally? `npm uninstall -g yarn`. Maybe it would be better to fix the problems you encounter moving code, though…

Comment: That didn't work. Still using Yarn.

Comment: You might have to delete the associated files. Like the yarn lock file etc..

Comment: You have to uninstall this with program which you've used when installed it. npm list -g --depth=0 shows your global npm packages. In my situation I have installed yarn with brew on MacOS, so ```brew uninstall yarn``` worked perfect for me

Comment: npm uninstall -g yarn worked for me

Answer (score 430):

Depends on **how you installed it**:

**brew**: `brew uninstall yarn`

**tarball**: `rm -rf "$HOME/.yarn"`

**npm**: `npm uninstall -g yarn`

**ubuntu**: `sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn`

**centos**: `yum remove yarn`

**windows**: `choco uninstall yarn` (or go to control panel > add/remove programs and uninstall it from there)

Comment: `npm uninstall -g yarn` doesn't work. It simply reports `up to date in 0.067s` and does nothing.

Comment: I've tried all of these that apply (unbuntu), but I get `$ eslint
bash: /home/.../.yarn/bin/eslint: No such file or directory`

Comment: To answer my own question - use `hash -r` to clear bash's hash and avoid restarting your shell.

Comment: what is this ? "windows" "npm".... the npm is already in windows! probably you meant choco? you messing OS with other packages... a mess...

Comment: @Vince Maybe you are on Windows? If so, see the answers of Alireza Fattahi and Raja Rahul on how to overcome the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I am on windows. I tried the advice here and  tried finding where on windows my yarn was installed. So, I ran the command "which yarn" (I have cygwin installed) -- I found that yarn  was installed in the "Program Files (x86)" directory -- so I knew that it was a standalone installation and was not part of choco or npm, etc. So, I uninstalled it from the OS installed software list.

Comment: @anjanb no need for cygwin/which, nowadays windows has "where".

Comment: **windows:** Control Panel -> Programs And Features -> Yarn -> Uninstall

Comment: on Mac, I run sudo npm uninstall -g yarn

Answer (score 200):

Try this, it works well on macOS:

```
$ brew uninstall --force yarn
$ npm uninstall -g yarn
$ yarn -v
```

> v0.24.5 (or your current version)

```
$ which yarn
```

> /usr/local/bin/yarn

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yarn
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
$ which yarn
```

> yarn not found

```
$ brew install yarn 
$ brew link yarn
$ yarn -v
```

> v1.17.3 (latest version)

Or you could install it as recommended on the website (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable) through npm using:

```
$ npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: Absolutely the most helpful answer! Tried all the other suggestions for removing yarn and couldn't find it until I did `which yarn`

Comment: I needed a `rm -rf ~/.yarn`

Comment: Most concise answer here. This resolved installation via Yarn's installation script as well. And the brew -force helped Homebrew with downloading a new copy of the package. Thank you

Comment: What is the equivalent command of 'which yarn' in windows?

Comment: if you removed the `/usr/local/bin` files manually and reinstalled yarn and now get errors like `/usr/bin/yarn no such file or directory` you need to restart your terminal

Comment: If using yarn > 2 you need to delete the `.yarn` folder in your project.

Comment: @GeroldMeisinger if you reinstalled with corepack, then run `yarn set version stable` afterwards, that should fix it.

Answer (score 54):

Didn't see the answer that worked for me, so here it is: On my OSX system I found yarn at `~/.yarn/bin/yarn`. `rm -rf ~/.yarn` took care of it.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using `corepack` and previously ran the command `corepack enable`, then you can **uninstall yarn** via the following command:

```sh
corepack disable yarn
```

Comment: I also installed Yarn through corepack. I tried this , its not working.  corepack is the recommended way they put on there website to install "Yarn" now. But there is no command for Uninstalling Yarn on there website. if you know of another way to uninstall "Yarn", for people that originally installed it through corepack. Please let me know.

Comment: Update, the command you put worked. I just had to enter the command inside the "Run as Administrator" mode in the "Command Prompt", since this was how i originally installed it. Thankyou,

Answer (score 33):

on windows: Go to "Add or remove programs" in control panel (or open the start menu and search for "remove program")

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3331

Answer (score 16):

If you installed with brew, try `brew uninstall yarn` at terminal prompt.   Also remember to remove yarn path info in your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 10):

In case you installed **yarn** globally like this

```
$ sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Just run this in terminal

```
$ sudo npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Tested now on my local machine running Ubuntu. Works perfect!

Comment: yes, how to unistall Yarn, something is not clear for you?

Comment: See the comments.

Comment: Tested now on *my* local machine running Ubuntu and didn't do anything at all. It reports `up to date in 0.067s`, but doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Great the `sudo` detail. Without it there is a successful message but the global `yarn` package doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using macOS. I had a few versions of yarn installed with Homebrew, which I uninstalled with `brew uninstall --force yarn`. I then installed the latest version 1.7.0 of Yarn using Homebrew `brew install yarn`

But still when I ran `which yarn`, it returned /Users/Me/.yarn/bin/yarn, and `yarn --version` returned 0.24.6. There was no mention of Yarn in ~/.bash_profile, but my ~/.bashrc file contained the line `export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"` indicating that I must have previously installed Yarn globally, but I only wanted to use the latest version that I just installed with Homebrew.

So I uninstalled Yarn globally by running `npm uninstall -g yarn; rm -rf ~/.yarn`, then editing the file ~/.bashrc by changing the line to `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/yarn:$PATH"` and running `source ~/.bashrc` to update the PATH in the terminal session. Then when I ran `which yarn` it returned /usr/local/bin/yarn, and when I ran `yarn --version` it returned
1.7.0

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful to mac users

Answer (score 8):

I tried the **Homebrew** and **tarball** points from [the post by sospedra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45914006/5285297). It wasn't enough.

I found yarn installed in: `~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yarn`

I ran `yarn global remove yarn`. Restarted terminal and it was gone.

Originally, what brought me here was yarn reverting to an older version, but I didn't know why, and attempts to uninstall or upgrade failed.

When I would checkout an older branch of a certain project the version of yarn being used would change from `1.9.4` to `0.19.1`.

Even after taking steps to remove yarn, it remained, and at `0.19.1`.

Comment: This answer saved me from wrong repo to fetch packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

What I've done on my side:

Went to the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and deleted the `yarn` folder inside it.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't uninstall yarn on windows and I tried every single answer here, but every time I ran `yarn -v`, the command worked. But then I realized that there is another thing that can affect this.

If you on windows (not sure if this also happens in mac) and using [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), one problem that can happen is that you have installed nvm without uninstalling npm, and the working `yarn` command is from your old yarn version from the old npm.

So what you need to do is follow [this step from the nvm docs](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#uninstall-existing-npm)

> You should also delete the existing npm install location (e.g. "C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm"), so that the nvm install location will be correctly used instead. Backup the global npmrc config (e.g. C:\Users&lt;user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc), if you have some important settings there, or copy the settings to the user config C:\Users&lt;user>.npmrc.

And to confirm that you problem is with the old `npm`, you will probably see the `yarn.cmd` file inside the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder.

Answer (score 5):

npm uninstall yarn removes the yarn packages that are installed via npm but what yarn does underneath the hood is, it installs a software named yarn in your PC. If you have installed in Windows, Go to add or remove programs and then search for yarn and uninstall it then you are good to go.

Comment: best way under Windows

Answer (score 4):

For Windows User:

Just use the installer file(i.e yarn-1.22.4.msi in my case) to **uninstall** yarn.

Once you open the installer you will get three options, i.e to install, repair and uninstall yarn from your machine.
Select **uninstall** and it will remove all the yarn files from your pc.

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac neither of these regular methods to uninstall Yarn worked:

brew: `brew uninstall yarn`

npm: `npm uninstall -g yarn`

Instead I removed it manually by typing `rm -rf ~/.yarn` (thanks user elthrasher) and deleting the two symbol links *yarn* and *yarnpkg* from `usr/local/bin`.
Afterwards `brew install yarn` gave me the latest version of Yarn.

---

Background: The fact that I had a very outdated version of Yarn installed gave me utterly incomprehensible errors while trying to install additional modules to a project set up with Vue CLI Service and Vue UI, which apparently uses Yarn 'under the hood'. I generally use NPM so it took me a while to figure out the cause for my trouble. Naturally googling error messages produced by such module incompatibilities presented no clues. With Yarn updated everything works just perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

For windows user:

`npm uninstall -g yarn`

For Mac user:

`$ npm uninstall -g yarn`

It will completely be remove yarn for your system.

Answer (score 3):

If on your system, Yarn is provided from Node.js, through `corepack`, then, you can choose which version of Yarn you want to use, with the following:

> ```
> corepack prepare yarn@x.y.z --activate
> ```

*–as per https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#upgrading-the-global-versions*

Answer (score 2):

In the case of windows, after executing `npm uninstall -g yarn`, still if yarn did not uninstalled, then go to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local" and remove the yarn folder.

Close the cmd and reopen the cmd and execute `yarn` . it will give you message `'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

If you are still getting errors after deleting ~/.yarn about files not being found, don't forget to delete the yarn rc file:

```sh
rm ~/.yarnrc.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the other answers a bit inadequate since I wanted to "completely" remove yarn from my Mac (M1). I found this worked:

1. First remove it how you installed it i.e. same [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45914006/997147).
2. Remove the cache. For example on my Mac I ran:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Yarn
```

3. Remove the global node_modules cache of Yarn:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/yarn
```

`yarn cache clean` did not help get rid of the above which tool significant space.

4. Remove any other Yarn-related config files:

```
rm -rf ~/.yarn
rm ~/.yarnrc
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yarn v3^ doesn't install via npm**.

It installs via corepack. See [installation instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install).

If your install process looked like:

```
corepack enable
corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate
```

And, if you're on Ubuntu (or perhaps similar, I only tested on Ubuntu), then your uninstall process will look like:

```
yarn --version
```

Returns:

```
3.50
```

You're on yarn v3! Find out where it's installed.

```
which yarn
```

Returns

```
/home/caleb/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/yarn
```

Delete from nvm

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/yarn
rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/yarnpkg
```

Doing `yarn` now will resolve to `/usr/local/bin/yarn` so you need to delete that as well.

```
yarn --version
which yarn
```

returns:

```
bash: /home/caleb/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/yarn: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/yarn
```

So remove that as well. You might need `sudo`. Especially when using `sudo`, you should not blindly copy/paste commands you find on the internet, so type out the below manually.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

Now `yarn` should be uninstalled.

```
yarn --version
```

Returns:

```
Command 'yarn' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install cmdtest
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to uninstall yarn completely for Mac Users

```
sudo npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **2023**: If you used Corepack to active Yarn, you can run the following

```
corepack disable
yarn -v
```

Then, remove any temp folders and files.
This works if you didn't originally install Yarn using `npm install --force -g yarn`. Corepack doesn't let you have multiple instances of Yarn if you activated Yarn using Corepack. Hence, why some might use `--force`.

Corepack [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/corepack.html) on Yarn.
Yarn [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) on Yarn2.x (not classic version 1.x)

Answer (score 0):

Try "`npm uninstall -g yarnpkg`"(*global*) or "`npm uninstall yarnpkg`"(*local*) if you installed it with **npm**.
That's what worked for me.
If that still doesn't work and you installed it with npm,
 do "`npm list -g`" to check if you installed it globally or "`npm list`" if you installed it locally.
 Hope that helps anyone having this problem. :D

EDIT: Found something if you installed yarn with .msi executable you have to install it the normal windows way.

Comment: This does nothing (just like `npm uninstall -g yarn`). I did install yarn globally, but `npm list -g` doesn't show anything containing the string `yarn`.

Comment: This worked for me where `npm uninstall -g yarn` did not

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove(delete) the `Yarn` folder from drive and then run `npm uninstall -g yarn` again to reinstall it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

I need to do these steps to completely remove the `yarn` from the system.

1. Go to `add or remove programs` and then search for yarn and `uninstall` it(if you installed it with the .msi)
2. `npm uninstall -g yarn` (if you installed with npm)
3. `Remove` any existing `yarn folders` from your `Program Files (x86)` (`Program Files (x86)\Yarn`).
4. Also need to `delete` your `Appdata\local\yarn folder` ( type `%LOCALAPPDATA%` in the run dialog box `(win+R)`, it opens a local folder and there you'll find the yarn folder to `delete`)
5. Finally,check your user directory and `remove all .yarn folder, .yarn.lock file, .yarnrc` etc ( from `C:\Users\<user>\`)

Answer (score 0):

It really works when I'm still getting errors after deleting ~/.yarn

`rm ~/.yarnrc.yml`

We must delete `.yarnrc.yml` or `.yarnrc` file

Answer (score 0):

I had an error with re-linking and bin logs:

> error Could not write file "/yarn-error.log": "EROFS: read-only file
> system, open '/yarn-error.log'" error An unexpected error occurred:
> "EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/node_modules'". info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this
> command.

To solve this I did this:

```bash
cd /tmp
mkdir yarntest
cd yarntest
yarn add react || fail_with_log
```

Answer (score -2):

`ng set --global packageManager=npm` OR `ng set --global packageManager=yarn`

Answer (score -2):

Just copy this command and your problem will be fixed.

> npm uninstall yarn