# How to uninstall Node, NPM, yarn

Tags: unix, npm, terminal, yarnpkg

I'm on a Mac (High Sierra 10.13.3). I switched from NPM to yarn a few weeks back. Recently, yarn has been giving me issues when attempting to global install various tools and libraries (webpack, etc) saying that "an incompatible module "node" was found. Expected version 6.11.0". I've tried using NVM, but I only get back a response that says "This is not the package you are looking for".

Now, my NPM commands return the following error: "Cannot find module './lib/utils/unsupported.js' ... "

I've also already tried simply reinstalling NPM, Node, and yarn.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few important links that would help you:

Uninstall yarn: [How Do I Uninstall Yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334978/how-do-i-uninstall-yarn)

Uninstall `node` and `npm`: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I would recommend you to use `node` and `npm` with the help of `NVM`.
you can refer link below for same:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-node-js-via-nvm-node-version-manager-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

Updating your node.js to the newest version could resolve your issue. And if not try running this:

```
yarn add prettier --ignore-engines
```