# Cannot find module 'hardhat/config' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, solidity, yarnpkg, hardhat

I'm setting up a new project with hardhat, using typescript and yarn.

I'm following https://hardhat.org/guides/typescript.html and when I get to the step "*We need to apply three changes to your config for it to work with TypeScript:*" there is an instruction to update the `hardhat.config.js` to `hardhat.config.ts`

The instructions and the example code say to put `import { task } from "hardhat/config";` but vscode and the compiler say `Cannot find module 'hardhat/config' or its corresponding type declarations.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add this import to your hardhat config file?

```
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
```

And be careful to install all necessary types:

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as well. I then tried using `npm` instead of the `yarn` package manager and the error got resolved.

I'd recommend [uninstalling and reinstalling yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334978/how-do-i-uninstall-yarn) and check if the error gets resolved, or use the `npm` package manager instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command:

```bash
npm install -D hardhat-deploy
```

Then, `require("hardhat-deploy");`.